# Insert Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables articles and users.

I want to insert title, content and name into the article table.

I have the the users id stored in a session, is there a way using an insert select query to add title, content and name to the article table whilst getting the name from the users table using the id.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO article (title, content, name) VALUES ($post['title'], $post['content'], name) SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = mySessionId
```

Comment: Your schema is wrong: you should store the ID and use `JOIN` to get the name. This is basic normalization (http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/sql-design-why-you-need-database-normalization) or face update anomalies

Comment: Please escape those values before putting them in your database for the sake of humanity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement,

```
$title = $post['title'];
$content = $post['content'];
$insertStatement = "INSERT INTO article (title, content, name)  
                    SELECT '$title', '$content', name 
                    FROM users 
                    WHERE id = mySessionId";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)